# Replacing potentiometer with a Hall sensor in PWM DC motor control module

Tags: pwm, potentiometer, motor-controller, hall-effect

I have a DC motor speed controller (PWM) that uses a 100 kΩ potentiometer to adjust motor speed. I also have an electronic throttle pedal that used a 49E Hall-Effect sensor (+5 V, 0.8-4.2 V signal, 1 K
KΩ). I want to use this pedal with this speed controller.

I measured the voltage drop across the potentiometer and it is 5 V. I confirmed that the pedal's signal changes from 0.8 V (released) to 4.2 V (fully pressed) when given 5 V.

What would be a right way to replace the potentiometer in the speed control unit with a Hall-effect sensor? Note that I would prefer to preserve full speed control range (from 0% to 100%).

If you're curious about my application: replacing binary on/off throttle in kids ride on car.

**UPDATE 1**

PWM controller built-in potentiometer works like this:

- Max speed: GND to wiper = 0 V, wiper to V+ = 5 V
- Min speed: GND to wiper = 5 V, wiper to V+ = 0 V

And Hall-effect pedal is opposite:

- Max speed (fully pressed): GND to signal = 4.2 V
- Min speed: GND to signal = 0.8 V

So as a drop-in replacement pedal it will behave more like a break pedal :)

**UPDATE 2**

On further examination, it appears that the potentiometer's GND (I mean, one of its legs that I referred above as GND) is connected directly to input GND of the PWM controller (where the negative terminal from battery goes). So, from a practical standpoint, it's probably safe to assume that I also have GND - Xv at my disposal (Xv however is variable, since it's coming from an unregulated battery).

But I think this extra voltage source makes this question less general and less useful for other people.

Comment: What voltage do you measure between the two far ends of the pot? It will probably be constant no matter what the pot is adjusted to. Then you need to run your hall-sensor through an opamp circuit that offsets and amplifies so the 0.8 and 4.2V gets remapped of 0 and Vpotmax.

Comment: @DKNguyen As I mentioned, voltage drop on the pot is 5V. Yes, the range difference is what bothers me. Can you be more specific on op-amp approach? AFAIK, they don't really do rail-to-rail, so I still will have a gap at least on one end of the spectrum (will not go to 5V, will be same ~4V upper range). I have 12V input of course, but I have no idea what kind of PWM circuit interference I can cause by powering op-amp from it...

Comment: I will post circuit. Just don't have time at the moment. You're saying the pot only adjusts from 0-4V? You could, but do not need to, power the opamp from the 12V if you add some decoupling caps and stuff. But best to just power straight off the two end terminals of the pot you measured the 5V between after you cut it out and inject the output into where the center terminal of the pot was.

Comment: @DKNguyen pot on PWM controller adjusts from 0 to 100K or from 0 to 5V.

Comment: So what did you mean by "*they don't really do rail-to-rail, so I still will have a gap at least on one end of the spectrum (will not go to 5V, will be same ~4V upper range*"? Rail to rail opamps exist and are not uncommon.

Comment: @DKNguyen My understanding was that rail-to-rail op-amps are just "closer" to rails than regular op-amps, but still not close enough. Was I wrong? I'm looking up some data sheets to confirm that.

Comment: It will be close enough for your purposes. We're talking like within 5mV or less.

Comment: This website has as schematic editor. Please draw what you mean by your Update. It sounds like you're saying you have a negative supply but I highly doubt that is the case.

Comment: No, there is no negative supply. All I'm saying is that there is a common wire that connects input `V-` (12V-19V) with potentiometer's `V-`. Potentiometer's `V+` is at 5v, which seems to be regulated, since it doesn't change with the input voltage. All I'm saying that I also have `V+` from the input voltage in addition to that.

Comment: It was expected that the "GND" of your pot actually was connected to the negative terminal of the battery and GND of the PWM controller. I had already assumed that when you first said pot GND pin. It's just a bit confusing when you start calling GND terminals negative terminals.

Comment: Well, it's a DC controller which is not **really** grounded (not even to the chassis). So, in my mind, ground is just a conceptual thing in such case and it's where `V-` goes. I'm quite lame at this though, correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: "Ground" is technically misused everywhere to refer to the reference rail, but there is a difference when systems have -V, 0V, and +V. If you wish, just say 0V instead of GND (and especially -V because -V implies there is a negative voltage rail somewhere below the reference rail). Some systems do use -V to refer to the reference rail in unipolar systems because in those systems it it is opposite of +V but that's just wrong. The reference rail is always 0V and is what we mean when we say GND, when we are misusing it to refer to something not actually grounded or earthed.

Comment: wonder.mice ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz0Fyp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This won't reverse it. Will continue to look at it tommorrow. I'm not sure I can do it without a negative supply.

https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEA2AzNA7ATi8gHACxhaKTJYgIaWWQBQAhiAEx57hbMgGpfFfswSALRDw8eFGi5myBGDxyCyMs1QUYM5GhwZlYDAlbiJdAO4s24MF1aCMyKOe68OXHnxtOATpcFePay5IcAR4Ol8bf1srMC8QsFNfOxZIdhTmBEcEsLg6AHM-Fiyi1EgCHyLmNLdU9gTTAHkXPk5uXFqQ+gAHWurBNszsqCdC-mLHcbKK+gA3cGMhhfSakIqCBMwWaCQunYLlicPmDGCDqPAVQ4Ns5wv+vtW6VBnoPAA1AB0AZwAvAFMAHb-XybDBgHhGPD8aHwZj-YTUELBN50X7XK4XOK2KQfH4A4HeCLXLwXAj1EDqPIAJUO5IxIzWIV2jP2AHsQBRkDNuJAsOwkbB4FgHFlMiMwHQOexuSMNvzxFIJMwCEQNshxRBJUA

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, really appreciate it. I tried to simulate your circuit, but DC swipe produces several megavolts on output :) I came up with simplified version that simulates well, but still needs to be reversed, which turned out to be tricky: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/9n5k5gsjrsvu/throttle/

Comment: I built it for visual purposes so opamp power pins might be swapped, and labels are for human eyes, not parsers, etc. Use Falstad instead

Comment: After some pondering I was able to reverse with a second op-amp: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/9n5k5gsjrsvu/throttle, but I'm sure it's possible to do better than that. I also need to read more about Zener diodes and capacitors, since I don't really understand why you put them there.

Comment: The zener is providng a 0.8V reference which gets subtracted from your input signal which shifts your 0.8-4.2V signal to 0-3.4V signal, prior to being amplified 1.5x relative to GND to become 0-5V. The capacitor is there because if the opamp needs a quick burst of current, the power supply isn't fast enough and too far away which will cause the opamp to misbehave.